# Core Data alternative

Tags: ios, class, oop, core-data, model

I'm hitting a few snags when using Core Data to define my model.

**1. Can't create objects on-the-fly.**

I want to be able to create an object like below and go on adding values to its properties.

```
let action = Action()
action.desc = "hello"
```

But if you're using Core Data model classes, you can't do this because you'd get the error **Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class**. You have to create a new objects using `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:` and all.

**2. Can't use the class type as a return type in functions.**

When using Core Data, I keep a separate file to put all the fetching/saving methods. In it, I have a method which used to retrieve all the `Action` objects as an array.

```
public func loadActions() -> [Action] {
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Action", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext!)
    fetchRequest.entity = entityDescription

    var error: NSError?
    let result = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error)

    return result!
}
```

I can't use the type `Action` to create a typed array because I'd get the error **Method cannot be declared public because its result uses an internal type**. So I have to get the array as an array of `AnyObject`s and then cast them to `Action` whenever I have to use them.

**3. Can't have methods within the class.**

I know you could create categories back in Objective-C and put all the methods in it. I guess the equivalent in Swift is extensions(?). But it'd be nice if you could have the class and its methods altogether in the same place.

Say I take the OO road and create my entire model the normal way and this brings to my question. How and where can I save these objects?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but I don't think points 2 and 3 are valid?

2. Don't make your method public - the issue here isn't anything to do with core data, it's to do with Swift's access levels. You can't make a public method `loadActions` that returns an internal type `Action`. You have to either make `Action` public, or make the method internal (i.e. delete the word `public`)
3. You can have the methods in the class - just write them in there? And even if you need to use an extension, you can still put it in the same file?

PS If you do find a good Swift alternative, please let me know. I'm looking for one at the moment - thats how I found your question in the first place!